# call activity from a library project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library

I have a problem. I have make an Android project as Library and i want to call an activity inside this library from a difference project. In the different project i have go to the properties and choose the first project to be the library.

The library project have some packages. The package name which contains the activity is com.jwetherell.augmented_reality.activity -> Demo.java

Now in the other project i want to call the Demo.java activity from this package com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide -> MainActivity.java

I'm trying to call it like this

```
public void Nearme(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.jwetherell.augmented_reality.activity.Demo"));
}
```

but i have problems. I have to write something in the AndroidManifest?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your activity must be listed in a manifest.

Something like:

```
<activity android:name="com.jwetherell.augmented_reality.activity.Demo" />
```

Or if the package name is 'com.jwetherell.augmented_reality' you only have to specify this:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.Demo" />
```

Comment: my main package in the AndroidManifest is com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide. The com.jwetherell.augmented_reality is the library package. So i have just to put in the manifest the
`<activity android:name="com.jwetherell.augmented_reality.activity.Demo" />` in my main manifest?